# Loopback 4 - JWT authentication - error with given UserRepository

Tags: authentication, jwt, loopbackjs, loopback4

First of all, I have to say I'm new to TypeScript and moreover that since I cannot find a single tutorial about LB and JWT authentication that seems to work correctly from the beginning to the end I had to follow more than one and try to put the pieces together while coding.

Started following [this article](https://medium.com/loopback/add-jwt-authentication-in-your-loopback-4-application-325137642c2c) on Medium, but did feels as something were missing, so switched to [`@loopback/authentication-jwt` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopback/authentication-jwt) and find out I had to make my own (empty) `User` model that extends LB's one just to have its table created, so far so good, so got back to Medium.

The real problem arise when trying to add the controller: copy-pasted [the linked controller file](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo-jwt/src/controllers/user.controller.ts) and fixed any import to use `@loopback/authentication-jwt` own `UserRepository` class, but I when trying to register a new user via the `/signup` route I get back a 500 response with an error at line [#156](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo-jwt/src/controllers/user.controller.ts#L156) of given controller file:

```
Request POST /signup failed with status code 500. TypeError: this.userRepository.userCredentials is not a function
    at UserController.signUp (/home/node/app/dist/controllers/user.controller.js:78:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/rest/dist/providers/invoke-method.provider.js:37:32
    at async /home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/express/dist/middleware-interceptor.js:82:25
    at async /home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/express/dist/middleware-interceptor.js:82:25
    at async /home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/rest/dist/providers/send.provider.js:39:32
    at async MySequence.handle (/home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/rest/dist/sequence.js:201:9)
    at async HttpHandler._handleRequest (/home/node/app/node_modules/@loopback/rest/dist/http-handler.js:64:9)
```

Inspecting `UserRepository` code I can see that

```js
export declare class UserRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<User, typeof User.prototype.id, UserRelations> {
    // ...
    readonly userCredentials: HasOneRepositoryFactory<UserCredentials, typeof User.prototype.id>;
    // ...
}
```

and digging deeper inspecting `HasOneRepositoryFactory` I see this:

```js
export interface HasOneRepositoryFactory<Target extends Entity, ForeignKeyType> {
    /**
     * Invoke the function to obtain HasOneRepository.
     */
    (fkValue: ForeignKeyType): HasOneRepository<Target>;
    /**
     * Use `resolver` property to obtain an InclusionResolver for this relation.
     */
    inclusionResolver: InclusionResolver<Entity, Target>;
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something about TS syntax, but to me the given user controller code seems to be correct and calling  `this.userRepository.userCredentials(savedUser.id)` at line 156 should not give any error, but still I get it.

Probably I'm missing something else about LB itself, but can't figure out what.

#### Update #1

@ShubhamP find out an issue about my problem:
https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/issues/6964

#### Update #2

Created Github repo with current project state: https://github.com/xfudox/test-lb4

Just start the project with `docker compose up -d --build`, then log into the node container, install the dependancies and run with `npm run start`

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example on github or codesandbox?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/issues/6964

Comment: @ShubhamP that's exactly the same error, I'll upload a simplified version of my current project as soon as i can, i.e. monday

Comment: Try to display the contents of this.userRepository, the property may not be initialized

Comment: @ShubhamP I've added a link to a github repo as you asked